# Difference in # questions tagged

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

If you look at the Tagged questions page of a specific tag, for example [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), you will get another count than if you woold look at the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) page of that tag.

Questions page:
[image]

Top users page:
[image]

The difference is quite small here, but I noticed that in other tags, for example the [dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo) tag, there is a difference of 177 questions. And for other tags, for example the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, the question count (at the moment) is the same at both pages.

Is there a different calculation used, or are the results cached for a different amount of time?

Comment: Caching, there is **always** caching going on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that was my first idea as well, but in the Dojo tag the difference is more than 170 questions, which is about the amount of questions asked in a month for that tag, isn't that weird? That would mean that the cache on the top users page isn't invalidaded for like a month or so?

Comment: And the counters seem to go up at the same time, with the same difference, now 3 new questions have been posted in the PHP tag, and one counter says 614,286 and the other one says 614,298 (they both went up with 3).

Comment: Right; if the difference remains constant then there is a query bug going on perhaps. I'd say that for less-busy tags the caching could be *stronger* as there are fewer events to purge the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual:

http://shouldiblamecaching.com